# Displaying the input from keypad on a LCD screen using Arduino

Tags: arduino, lcd, keypad

I want an Arduino code to give the output in following format on LCD display

If the user click 'A', 1, 2, 3 from the keypad, LCD should display Hi:1,2,3,

This is what I have tried but I cannot figure out a way to build the code as I am a beginner in arduino

```
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>


const byte numRows= 4;
const byte numCols= 4;

char keymap[numRows][numCols]= {
    {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
    {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
    {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
    {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};

byte rowPins[numRows] = {9,8,7,6};      // Pin Assign
byte colPins[numCols] = {5,4,3,2};      // Pin Assign

Keypad myKeypad= Keypad(makeKeymap(keymap), rowPins, colPins, numRows, numCols);

// LCD
//                RS E  D4 D5 D6 D7
LiquidCrystal lcd(A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5);   // Pin Assign


void setup()
{   
    lcd.begin(16, 2);       
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("PUSH ANY KEY! ");
    lcd.cursor();
    lcd.blink();
}


void loop(){
    char keypressed = myKeypad.getKey();
    if (keypressed != NO_KEY){
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(keypressed);
        lcd.print(':');
        lcd.setCursor(3, 0);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a state machine, where the change in the state happens when you receive the `'A'` char. So, while you do not receive the `'A'` char, your state machine keeps in the busy-wait (`while (keypressed != 'A')` ).

Once the `'A'` is received, you then are going to check the next 3 chars received, and verify if they match what you expect (`'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`).

If you receive it in any different order, then the loop breaks, and the verification fails at the statement `if (i == 4)`. In other words, as soon as you receive a number that you do not expect, the loop breaks and the verification fails.

Here is what you could add in your `loop()` code:

```c
void loop() {
  char expected[3] = { '1', '2', '3' };
  int i = 0;
  char keypressed = myKeypad.getKey();
  while (keypressed != 'A')
    ;

  while (i < 4) {
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      if (keypressed != expected[i])
        break;
  }

  if (i == 4)
    lcd.print("Hi:1,2,3");
}
```